# how to read & seprated data in single column

Tags: sql, hive

Field Description:

User_id Unique identifier of every user following these creators 
Creator_id List of creator ids separated by ‘&’

```
User_id,Creator_IDs
U100,A300&A301&A302
U101,A301&A302
U102,A302
U103,A303&A301&A302
U104,A304&A301
U105,A305&A301&A302
U106,A301&A302
U107,A302
```

Note: I have to remove U and A before the values, I though I could use substring for U but what can I do for A since it is varying.

Moreover going forward I have to use this data to have distinct creator_id and subsequent user following them.

Comment: update your question and add  the expected  result

Comment: First of all I need to read the data removing U from user_id and A from creator_id. So I guess we can read creator_id in array format.

Comment: But how do I remove A from varying fields and delimited by &?

Comment: as before  ... update your question  and add  a clear expected  result based on your data sample  ..  not words ..

Comment: I think it requires output like this:

100, 300 

100, 301

100, 302

101, 301

101, 302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using regexp_replace eg:

```
select regexp_replace(User_id, "^U", "")
 , regexp_replace(regexp_replace(Creator_IDs, "A", ""), '&', ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REPLACE` function to remove A from the string. The function would be something like this -

```
SELECT REPLACE('A300&A301&A302', 'A','') AS NewString;
```

For the entire query -

```
select concat (REPLACE('U100', 'U',''),',',REPLACE('A300&A301&A302', 'A',''));
```

You can use this to see how it works. For your query of course you have to use the column names -

```
select concat (REPLACE(user_id, 'U',''),',',REPLACE(Creator_Id, 'A',''));
```